# Exported feature, panelizer fields are unknown when installing in another environment

Tags: entities, panels, features, debugging

I can't seem to find out why my panelizer default layout is not being installed correctly after being exported using features. I am exporting a content type, with some default panelizer settings.

When I install it on another test environment, my panelizer layout settings are not set and many similarly named fields are shown, but shown as "Unknown." I have looked at all of my exported code, everything, I have even looked at tables that might have these configuration settings in the database.

No luck. Any panels/panelizer/features help is appreciated.

I'll post a few screenshots.

First image shows how the feature is being imported. Note the "Unknown" fields. Second image shows how the content type layout is setup before I export and install on another environment.

[image: This is how the feature is being imported. Note the "Unknown" fields.]
[image: This is how the content type layout is setup before I export and install on another environment.]